# Submit the same list using AsyncListDiffer, but the recycler view always auto scroll to top

Tags: android-recyclerview, android-diffutils, android-asynclistdiffer

I try to submit the same list using AsyncListDiffer, but the recycler view always auto scroll to top. When I debug I see the recyclerview auto scroll to top after calling submitList before areItemsTheSame method is called

```
class TestPlaceAdapter(
    private val itemClickCallback: (TestPlaceUi) -> Unit
) : RecyclerView.Adapter<TestPlaceAdapter.ItemViewHolder>() {

    private val differ = AsyncListDiffer(this, DiffCallback())
    private val listTest = mutableListOf<TestPlaceUi>()

    fun setData(listPlace: List<TestPlaceUi>) {
        if (listTest.size == 0) {
            listTest.addAll(listPlace)
            differ.submitList(listTest)
        } else {
            val test = mutableListOf<TestPlaceUi>().apply {
                addAll(listTest)
            }
            differ.submitList(test)
        }
    }

    private class DiffCallback : DiffUtil.ItemCallback<TestPlaceUi>() {
        override fun areItemsTheSame(oldItem: TestPlaceUi, newItem: TestPlaceUi): Boolean {
            return oldItem.id == newItem.id
        }

        override fun areContentsTheSame(oldItem: TestPlaceUi, newItem: TestPlaceUi): Boolean {
            return oldItem == newItem
        }
    }
    ...
 }
```

TestPlaceUi is the data class and doesn't override equal and hashcode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I detected my mistake caused by using another third party using skeleton. It reset adapter to recyclerview.